# Most efficient way to sum data in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, oracle

I am trying to create a friendly report summing enrollment for number of students by time of day. I initially started with loops for campusname, then time, then day and hibut it was extremely inefficient and slow. I decided to take another approach and select all the data I need in one select and organize it using c#.

[Raw Data View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zFwt.png)

My problem is I am not sure whether to put this into arrays, or lists, or a dictionary or datatable to sum the enrollment and organize it as seen below(mockup, not calculated).  Any guidance would be appreciated.

[Friendly View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOQH1.png)

Comment: You are able to pull the data into working memory from that chart I take it?

Comment: where is the data right now? If it is in a database, write a sum query

Comment: Make an object to represent the data you pull in, then make a list of objects. Loop through list and add everything up

Comment: You could look at Parallel LINQ (PLINQ)

Comment: @James I don't care if it is working memory or from the DB

Comment: @Emo it is in the database but as you will see on the first link it isn't as simple as a sum query which was my first option. It looped hundreds of times and was extremely inefficient.

Comment: @CSharpDev  I like it...I will try that.

Comment: @Geekender What I meant to confirm is that you don't need the process of pulling the data from the db as part of the solution, we can assume you know how to do that

Comment: I would suggest using a CTE to build the data you want and then selecting from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you only need to show the user some data (and not edit it) you may want to create a report.

Otherwise, if you only need sums, you could get all the data in an `IEnumerable` and call `.Sum()`. And as pointed out by colinsmith, you can use Linq in parallel.

But one thing is  definite though... If you have a lot of data, you don't want to do many queries. You could either use a `sum` query in SQL (if the data is stored in a database) or do the sum from a collection you've fetched.

You don't want to fetch the data in a loop. Processing data in memory is way faster than querying multiple times the database and then process it.

Comment: it is a lot of data and took about 15 mintues using loops. It worked but was unacceptable performance. Not sure how to organize it using SQL to format for quick import if that would be more efficient.

Comment: Can you show us the code you used to query your data (that took 15minutes) ? Some people could definitely help you figure things out from there.

Answer (score 0):

Normally I would advise you to do this in the database, i.e. a select using group by etc, I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out how your first picture relates to the second with regards to the days so I can't offer an example.

You could of course do this in C# as well using LINQ to objects but I would first try and solve it in the DB, you are better of performance and bandwidth wise that way.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you are exactly after. But from my understanding, i would suggest you to create a class to represent your enrollment

```
public class Enrollment
{
  public string CampusName { set;get;}
  public DateTime DateEnrolled { set;get;}
}
```

And Get all enrollment details from the database to a collection of this class

```
List<Enrollment> enrollments=db.GetEnrollments();
```

Now you can do so many operations on this Collection to get your desired data

Ex : If you want to get all Enrollment happened on Fridays

```
var fridaysEnrollMent = enrollments.
           Where(x => x.DateEnrolled.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday).ToList();
```

If you want the Count of Enrollments happened in `AA` campus

```
var fridayCount = fridaysEnrollMent .Where(d => d.CampusName == "AA").Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
select campusname, ssrmeet_begin_time, count(ssrmeet_monday), count(ssrmeet_tue_day) ..
from the_table
group by campusname, ssrmeet_begin_time
order by campusname, ssrmeet_begin_time
/
```

should be close to what you want. The count only counts the values, not the NULL's. It is also thousands of times faster than first fetching all data to the client. Let the database do the analysis for you, it already has all the data.

BTW: instead of those pics, it is smarter to give some ddl and insert statements with data to work on. That would invite more people to help to answer the question.